# Error while importing wmi

Tags: python, wmi

Im getting an error while importing wmi module

> > > import wmi
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > >           File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in 
> > >           from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
> > >           ImportError: No module named win32com.client

i have installed the module from

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/#downloads

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check sys.path to make sure the directory where the module is installed is in there, otherwise you have to add it (google PYTHONPATH windows for some help with that.)